# How to resolve Cannot read property 'match' of undefined while mobile number validation

Tags: jquery

On click of a submit button i am doing Form Validation

I am getting  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined in browser console

This is my code

```
<input type="button" id="btn" class="fillbtn" value="Submit">

$(document).on("click", "#btn", function (e) {

    alert('ddddddddd');

    var name = 'Kiran';
    var mobile = '8989899990'
    var email = 'gssaaj@gmail.com';
    if (!validateForm(name, mobile, email)) {

    } else {
        alert('Valid data');
    }
}); // close of save event listener


// Form Validation
function validateForm(name, mobile, email) {
    if (name == '' || name == 'undefined') {
        alert('Enter valid Name');
        return false;
    }
    if (mobile == '' || mobile == 'undefined') {
        alert('Enter valid Mobile');
        return false;
    }

    if (email == '' || email == 'undefined') {
        alert('Enter valid Email');
        return false;
    }

    if (!phonenumber(mobile)) {
        alert('Enter valid Mobile');
        return false;
    }

    return true;


}

// // Phone Number  Validation
function phonenumber(inputtxt) {
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
    if (inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Not a valid Phone Number");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Could anybody please let me know how to resolve this ??

Thanks in advance .

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ntynf5wc/

Comment: A string doesn't have a `value` property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of 'inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)' use 'inputtxt.match(phoneno)'

http://jsfiddle.net/ntynf5wc/1/

```
 if (inputtxt.match(phoneno)) {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already sending a value to the `phoneNumber()` function, hence need not do a `inputtxt.value.match`. Do `inputtxt.match` instead.